# Internet Explorer matrix transformation filter issue

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, filter

As one of my hobby projects, I'm developing an image effects plugin for jQuery. It's supposed to allow you to apply a few basic effects to an image, and does this by using the canvas HTML element or Internet Explorer filters, which ever are supported.

A demo page is available at: http://sandbox.odyniec.net/imgfx-new/.

I'm having a problem with the rotation effect, which is implemented with the matrix transformation filter (DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix).

If I just rotate the image, the resulting image appears fine. But, if I use another effect on the image before rotating, the rotated image gets broken, ie. a part of it turns black or white. You can see that on the demo page.

For example, use the `Invert` button, then `Rotate` by 20 degrees, you'll notice a black stripe where the blue tree should be. The actual filters that are applied to the image are displayed at the bottom of the page.

Am I missing something here, or could this be a browser bug?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set the css zoom value to 1. If that also doesn't work. It seems that this is really a bug in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a Browser bug to me.